# Procurve switch SFP only works when not firmly seated

Tags: networking

I have a Procurve switch with an SFP transceiver in Port 28. The switch will not bring this port online while the transceiver is securely seated and latched.

However, if I pull the transceiver out slightly so that it's not seated firmly, the module comes online.

Is this normal?

Comment: That sounds like either a faulty switch or a faulty transceiver. What happens if you try that transceiver in a different SFP port?

Comment: +1 for experimenting w/ other slots. Only other thing I could think of is taking some canned air and blowing out the slot, and also (gently) cleaning the connective surface on the tranceiver unit itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like dirty contacts on either the module or the switch.  Try cleaning them, or using a different module/slot.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not normal and indicative of a bad slot or SFP.  Try another SFP in that slot or your SFP transceiver in a different port to test which (if not both) is faulty.